# Can the kinetic friction turn to static?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces, friction

Lets take for example a mass pushed by some force F. The mass rests on a horizontal surface with friction. F is large enough that the object is moving and a kinetic friction force is applied on it. After some time I stop pushing the mass, from this moment till the mass stops what kind of friction works on the problem? (kinetic or static).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinetic friction acts till the body is in motion. As soon as it stops, no friction acts on it unless pushed by an external agent with force F<= Max. Static Friction.

Comment: "Kinetic friction acts till the body is in motion" - ?

Comment: Yes. Till the body is moving on the surface, kinetic friction acts on it. It is not a passive force

Comment: If the body is not in motion then it's experiencing static rather than kinetic friction, by definition...

Comment: No. Static force is passive in nature, contrary to the "active" nature of kinetic friction. So what it means is that till you apply no force to the body at rest, no friction acts on it be it kinetic or static. Static friction only acts when we have an external agent pushing/pulling the body. When it is overcome, the body starts moving and kinetic friction starts acting till the body comes back to rest.

Comment: No force, no movement = no friction. Force, no movement = static friction. Force or no force, movement = kinetic friction. "till the body is in motion" means it is *presently* not moving, so kinetic friction is not acting...

Comment: Yes. But your first sentence could land you in trouble otherwise. According to the first law of motion, there will be constant motion (rest or some velocity) unless a force acts on it. So a body can be moving even if there is no force acting on it. The only difference will be that, then the body can only move with a constant velocity

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, so I'll dismiss it as a digression. The point remains: "till the body is in motion" means the body is currently not moving, so "kinetic friction" does not apply. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Yeah. Keep it simple.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly when ever there is no external force working  if we have a movement only the kinetic friction will work? @PranshuMalik

Comment: @lemon : The intention of the 1st sentence is  *Kinetic friction acts **while** the body is in motion.* Allowance needs to be made for the use of English as a 2nd language.

Comment: @Shay yes. Whenever the body is originally moving, and is on a rough slab, it will only feel the kinetic friction.

Comment: @PranshuMalik Then what you said does not match what you *meant*, so you should correct it...